# DataGridView CheckBox Column - Show CheckBox but store String

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

Here is my code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlCommandBuilder cmbl;
    string con = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
    SqlDataAdapter sdaHFP;
    string QueryDgvHFP = "SELECT * FROM HFP";
    DataTable dtHFP;
    SqlConnection cn;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        sdaHFP = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryDgvHFP, con);
        dtHFP = new DataTable();
        sdaHFP.Fill(dtHFP);

        foreach (DataRow item in dtHFP.Rows)
        {
            int n = dgvHFP.Rows.Add();
            dgvHFP.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["HFP"].ToString();
            dgvHFP.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["YearPeriod"].ToString();
            if (item["Active"].ToString() == "Y")
            {
                dgvHFP.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dgvHFP.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = false;
            };
            dgvHFP.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["ID"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

That's was load data from Sql Query to DataGridView, And I was add a Button for execute update or insert within this code :

```
private void btUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cmbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(sdaHFP);
        sdaHFP.Update(dtHFP);
        MessageBox.Show("Success", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

When I Update / Insert data in `DataGridView` and click that Update Button, a Success MessageBox appears, but the Data in Database not Updated nor Inserted

Please help me solve this problem, why the Update Button doesn't work?

Thank You Very Much.

Comment: @M. Schena thanks for editing my question.

Comment: What makes you think that you are actually executing an UPDATE sql statement by using the Update() method (which is used to update the control in UI)?

Comment: You should bind the `DataGridView` To your `DataTable`, then when you change a cell value in grid, the change will apply on `DataTable`. Then you can use `Update` method.

Comment: @RezaAghaei can You explain me how to bind the  DataGridView to The DataTable please, I'm verry noob and green in C#. Thanks.

Comment: @Mac I posted a detailed answer for you. In the answer I showed you how to bind `DataGridView` to `DataTable` and more important, how to edit your string `Y` or `N` using a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`. The answer is tested and works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the `DataGridView` to `DataTable`, then when you change a cell value or add or remove rows, the changes apply on `DataTable`. Then you can save data table changes using a `TableAdapter`:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

**Note:** To store `true/false` or `Yes/No` values, it's better to use `bit` data type in sql server. But in the below example I supposed you need to store values as `Y/N` as `nvarchar(50)` and I setup a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` to support editing a string column.

**Example**

Suppose we have a table `Table1`:

```
Column1: int, primary key
Column2: nvarchar(50), Allows Null, Containing Y or N as vaule
```

And we want to edit data of `Table1` in a `DataGridView`:

[image]

Here is the code you can use to load and edit and save data:

```
private DataTable table; 
private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;

private void sampleForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var command = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
    var connection = @"Your connection string";
    table = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
    var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);

    //Set false as default value for Column2
    table.Columns["Column2"].DefaultValue = false;

    var column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column1.Name = "Column1";
    column1.DataPropertyName = "Column1";

    var column2 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    column2.Name = "Column2";
    column2.DataPropertyName = "Column2";
    column2.TrueValue = "Y";
    column2.FalseValue = "N";

    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column2);

    //Bind grid to table
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}

private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Save data
    this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    dataAdapter.Update(table);
}
```

Comment: It was error in saveButton when clicked :
 
"Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows."

Then I was add some code in saveButton :
"  SqlCommandBuilder cmbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter); 

And everything work fine as expected.

Thank You Very Much.......  I was learned so much from You.....

Comment: You are welcome :) By the way, the answer doesn't need any change. I used the command builder in `sampleForm_Load` and then used the same adapter to save data, so I don't need to use the command builder again in `saveButton_Click` anymore.